# Redirect HTTPS to HTTP in Controller

Tags: php, http, redirect, zend-framework, https

At the moment the redirect code redirects HTTPS → HTTPS. I tried stopping the page with `die($url)` to see if the PROTOCOL is HTTP and it was correct. But for some reason when I try PHP header location it redirects back to HTTPS protocol rather than HTTP

So when I use following code in my Zend predispatch method

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/blogs/');
```

it redirects to `https://www.example.com/blogs/` (HTTPS PROTOCOL)

whereas when I try

```
header("Refresh:0; url=http://www.example.com/blogs/");
```

it works fine. Meaning it redirects to HTTP protocol.

Note: The reason I need to do this inside the controller is that redirects depend on a special flagpole. I cannot do it with Apache config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this issue.

The problem was the redirection headers were being overridden by the loadbalancer. So there was some sort of policy set that if someone tries to redirect URL from one protocol to another it will not allow that causing the redirect loop that i was experiencing.

The solution in my particular case was another custom header that was needed to be sent which allowed scheme override in the loadbalancer.